# How to save a single desktop snapshot in jpg with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

The syntax for a desktop movie is

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 100 -s 1200x500 -i :0.0 \
-vcodec libx264  -threads 3 output.mp4
```

I want to take a single snapshot instead of a video and save it in `jgep`.

**Which `ffmpeg` command allow me to do so?**

Comment: Is using ffmpeg a hard requirement? It sounds like you would be better served by an image-centric tool instead.

Answer (score 8):

If you *want* to use ffmpeg, you can do :

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 1 -video_size 1200x500 -i :0.0 -vframes 1 output.jpeg
```

But I think there are better/simpler tools than ffmpeg to do that.